# How do I ensure that fgets accepts numbers with leading 0's accurately?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that essentially takes a user input and multiplies it by 12 and outputs that number.  I have gotten this down although I have ran into the following problem below.

```
expected output :   
./test  
minutes: 0000004  
bottles: 48  

actual output :  
$ ./test  
minutes: 0000004  
minutes: minutes: bottles: 48
```

I would like to fix this without having to change the minutesStr[4] to a bigger number.  One idea I would have is to change my buffer to store the value, cut the leading 0's off, and bring it out of the buffer.  I also upon research I  found that scanf would solve the leading 0 problem but I want to do this without using scanf because it is "bad".  Also i'm just trying to learn.

```
  // Set buffer size to 0 to fix printf/fgets problem
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);
char minutesStr[4]; // This limits minutes to < 999
char *end;
int minutes = 0;
int i = 0;
int offset;
do
{
  printf("minutes: ");
    // Takes in user input string, sizeof(string), from keyboard
  fgets(minutesStr, sizeof(minutesStr), stdin);
  while (minutesStr[i] == '0')
  {
    i++;
  }
  if (minutesStr[i] == '\n')
    for ( offset = 0; offset < i; offset++ )
    {
      minutesStr[offset] = minutesStr[offset + i];
    }
    // returms size of string up to \n and replaces it with null terminator
  minutesStr[strlen(minutesStr) - 1] = '\0';
    // minutes = (Convert the string into a long)
  minutes = strtol (minutesStr, &end, 10);
}
while ( minutes < 1 );

printf("bottles: %d\n", (minutes * 12));
return 0;
```

This is also my first question, so let me know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Are you memory limited so that you cannot use a buffer `minutesStr` larger than 4 byte?

Comment: ^^^ what @ChristophTerasa says.  If you are not on some RAM-restricted system, just put [128] and be done with it.

Comment: If you really want to keep `char minutesStr[4]` then `fgets` is not an option. You may try to with `fgetc`.

Comment: Move `printf("minutes: ");` outside the `do` loop. Have you considered what will happen if your number straddles two parts of the input read by `fgets`? And don't forget, the first parts of the input read, won't contain a `newline`. Much simpler to follow @MichaelWalz advice.

Comment: The basic idea is to provide a **large** buffer to `fgets()` so it can (virtually) always read a complete line, *then* parse that input (e.g. via `strtol()`). You are looking at user input. You cannot assume it will always be well-formed. Trying to limit yourself to too-small a buffer just leads to error-prone and hard to debug code. Don't do it.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa I feel that just increasing the buffer size is avoiding the problem since the user could just put more 0's in order to fill the buffer `minutesStr`.  
@MichaelWalz Thanks!  
@DevSolar I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
char minutesStr[4]; // This limits minutes to < 999
int minutes = 0;
int i = 0;
do {
    printf("minutes: ");

    do{
        fgets(minutesStr, sizeof(minutesStr), stdin);
        for(i = 0; minutesStr[i] == '0'; ++i)
            ;
    } while(i == sizeof(minutesStr) -1);
    if(i != 0 && !strchr(minutesStr, '\n')){
        int len = sizeof(minutesStr) - i -1;
        memmove(minutesStr, minutesStr + i, len);
        fgets(minutesStr + len, sizeof(minutesStr) - len, stdin);
    }
    minutes = strtol (minutesStr, NULL, 10);
} while ( minutes < 1);

printf("bottles: %d\n", (minutes * 12));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  One question though, how does the `fgets(minutesStr + len, sizeof(minutesStr) - len, stdin);` work without prompting the user for another input?  (I may be confused about how stdin works).

Comment: @DanN Overflow input is left in the stdin buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Read using `fgets()` and *then* parse.

Separate user input from input parsing. [@DevSolar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181356/how-do-i-ensure-that-fgets-accepts-numbers-with-leading-0s-accurately/37188856#comment61901857_37181356)

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

int n  = 0;
sscanf(buf, "%*[0-9]%n", &n);
// If input is only made up of 6 digits and line feed
if (n == 6 && buf[n] == '\n') {
  // Success
  int minute = atoi(buf);
} else {
  ; // Fail
}
```